# Android: I'm not able to display phone's images into my GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have implemented Gridview, but the images from the phone gallery is not appearing in the particular GridView.
The scroll seems to be big enough as the scrollbar appearing on the right side scrolls along to the bottom. Then why I couldn't see the images.

GalleryGridAdapter.java

```
package com.test.Adapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.test.R;

public class GalleryGridAdapter extends CursorAdapter
    {
    private Context mContext;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private int mColumnIndex;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public GalleryGridAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int ci) {
        super(context, c);
        mContext = context;
        mCursor = c;
        mColumnIndex = ci;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor curs)
    {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
        int id = curs.getInt(mColumnIndex);
        imageView.setImageURI( Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                String.valueOf(id)));
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor curs, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return new ImageView(context);
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public int mygetItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


}
```

MyActivity.java

```
 String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,  MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA};
    final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
    int columnIndex = 0;
    if (cursor != null) {
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewGallery);
        gridview.setAdapter(new GalleryGridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cursor, columnIndex));
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Log.e("selected Image",cursor.getColumnName(i)+"");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use xml code like :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bg_child">
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/FrameLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_gravity="top" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/photo_frame" android:textColor="@color/grey" android:text="@string/photogallery_txt"></TextView>
        <Button android:layout_gravity="right" android:id="@+id/btnMoreInfo" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:background="@drawable/my_child_button" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:text="@string/moreinfo_txt"></Button>
    </FrameLayout>
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

use code like :

```
public class GalleryPage extends Activity {

private static Uri[] mUrls = null;
private static String[] strUrls = null;
private String[] mNames = null;
private GridView gridview = null;
private Cursor cc = null;
private Button btnMoreInfo = null;
private ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
    btnMoreInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMoreInfo);
    // It have to be matched with the directory in SDCard
    cc = this.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            null);

    if (cc != null) {
        myProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(GalleryPage.this);
        myProgressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        myProgressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.pls_wait_txt));            
        myProgressDialog.show();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    cc.moveToFirst();
                    mUrls = new Uri[cc.getCount()];
                    strUrls = new String[cc.getCount()];
                    mNames = new String[cc.getCount()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < cc.getCount(); i++) {
                        cc.moveToPosition(i);
                        mUrls[i] = Uri.parse(cc.getString(1));
                        strUrls[i] = cc.getString(1);
                        mNames[i] = cc.getString(3);
                        //Log.e("mNames[i]",mNames[i]+":"+cc.getColumnCount()+ " : " +cc.getString(3));
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                myProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();
     gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
     gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

     gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
              int position, long id) {
           Intent i = new Intent(GalleryPage.this, BigImage.class);
           Log.e("intent : ", ""+position);
           i.putExtra("imgUrls", strUrls);
           i.putExtra("position", position);
           startActivity(i);
        }
     });
    }

    btnMoreInfo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(GalleryPage.this, ChildLogin.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * This class loads the image gallery in grid view.
 *
 */
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return cc.getCount();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.galchild, null);

        try {

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
            //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            // imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            Bitmap bmp = decodeURI(mUrls[position].getPath());
            //BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mUrls[position].getPath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            //bmp.
            TextView txtName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            txtName.setText(mNames[position]);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return v;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "***");
}

/**
 * This method is to scale down the image 
 */
public Bitmap decodeURI(String filePath){

    Options options = new Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    // Only scale if we need to 
    // (16384 buffer for img processing)
    Boolean scaleByHeight = Math.abs(options.outHeight - 100) >= Math.abs(options.outWidth - 100);
    if(options.outHeight * options.outWidth * 2 >= 16384){
        // Load, scaling to smallest power of 2 that'll get it <= desired dimensions
        double sampleSize = scaleByHeight
            ? options.outHeight / 100
            : options.outWidth / 100;
        options.inSampleSize = 
            (int)Math.pow(2d, Math.floor(
            Math.log(sampleSize)/Math.log(2d)));
    }

    // Do the actual decoding
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[512];  
    Bitmap output = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    return output;
}
```

}